# update dom to render results after api request

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

SOLVED: by adding this.tasks = resp.data in the functions so that it updates to the new state...

i'm currently working on a simple todo-list app in vuejs and i'm looking for a way to update the dom in a smooth way after doing the api request. The only way i've been able to display the changes directly after they've been made is by putting location.reload() in the response. I've been looking over some examples and guides and people seem to be able to do this with .bind(), but it's not working for me and i'm not content with the page flashing on every change you make.

```
//deletePost works for displaying changes but i don't want the page to flash on every update
deletePost(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`)
    .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data)
    location.reload(); 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }) 
},
  //this is how i've seen people doing it, but it's not working for me. 
  updatePost(selected, id) {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`,{ status: selected } )
    .then(function(response){
        console.log('saved successfully')
      }.bind(this));  
   }
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of reloading the page, where are you updating its local view of the state? I would expect a modification to `this.posts` in the `then` part of your delete/update methods..

Answer (score 0):

You shold have an array of tasks in your Vue component. Sending an http request deletes the resource from the server, but not locally. To delete the resource inside your component you'll need to do it in the .then() part for example like this:

```
data() return {
   tasks: []
},

deletePost(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`)
    .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data)
    // Here we delete the task from the component locally
    // Note that we only want to delete it if the request is successful
    let index= this.tasks.find(task => task.id === id)
    this.tasks.splice(index,1);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }) 
},
  //this is how i've seen people doing it, but it's not working for me. 
  updatePost(selected, id) {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`,{ status: selected } )
    .then(function(response){
        console.log('saved successfully')
      }.bind(this));  
   }
},
```

Comment: You are just missing deleting the data locally on the component, of which I added an example. Did you try if it works?

Comment: the request works but its still not updating after the request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying to my first post here so quickly, of course i should've provided the whole script and not just the api request...

```
  data () {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      formValue: '', 
      selected: '' 
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'fetchData', 
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/tasks')
      .then((resp) => {
        this.tasks = resp.data
        console.log(resp.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }, 
    deletePost(id) {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`)
        .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data)
        // Here we delete the task from the component locally
        // Note that we only want to delete it if the request is successful
        let index= this.tasks.find(task => task.id === id)
      this.tasks.splice(index,1);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }) 
    },
      //updates post status
      updatePost(selected, id) {
        axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`,{ status: selected } )
        .then(function(response){
            console.log('saved successfully')
          }.bind(this));  
      }
  },
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what your task looks like so it's just an example. What the code that deletes it in the component state does, is that it searches the tasks array for a task that has the certain Id and get's it's index. After you know the index of the task it deletes the task from the array. That's just an example, so it won't work for example if the task doesn't have id but rather Id or taskId.

Comment: all the tasks has an id which i use to delete and update them. The jsonobject looks like this:
{
        "_id": "59fc296ce2e82702e744dd1c",
        "name": "New task",
        "__v": 0,
        "status": "pending",
        "Created_date": "2017-11-03T08:31:40.805Z"
    }